# Asymptotics for quadratic polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Let $x$ be a real number, fix it. I would like to know if there is a way to count the number of integer coefficients quadratic polynomials $ax^2+bx+c>0,a<0$ of a fixed discriminant $D$ congruent to 0 or 1 modulo 4 and not being a square. An asymptotic would also be great ! Note that for $x$ rational there are finitely many forms. 
Thanks !

EDIT: Here is an example. Let $D=5$, then for $x=p/q\in \mathbb{Q}$, an element $Q(p/q)$ where $Q$ is our polynomial, is of the form $ap^2/q^2+bp/q+c$ and by assumption $b^2-4ac=5$. We can rewrite this as $5=b^2+4|a|c$ and multiplying by $q^2$ on both sides gives $5q^2=b^2q^2+4|a|cq^2$. By adding and substracting $4apbq$ and $4a^2p^2$ we obtain $$5q^2=(b^2q^2+4apbq+4a^2p^2)-4apbq-4a^2p^2+4|a|cq^2$$ $\iff$ $$5q^2=|bq+2ap|^2+4|a|(ap^2+bpq+cq^2)$$ Since $ap^2+bpq+cq^2>0$ by assumption and that $x=p/q$ is fixed, we obtain that this sum has finitely many integer solutions for $a,b,c$.

Comment: Does $ax^2+bx+c>0$ have to hold for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$? If so, then you necessarily need $a>0$ and $D<0$.

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain a bit better, I tried to plot $x^{2} + 4yz = 10$, 10 being the fixed discriminant I assume. And from the plot, I think the set of points satisfying this is an infinite set, and I don't see a reason why this set will have only finitely many integer points. The problem is interesting, would be nice to have more context or references.

Comment: Just edited @bjorn93

Comment: Just edited @SagarM